# To find the dll version of the file

Tags: c#, dll, compact-framework, windows-ce, .net-cf-3.5

I want to find the dll version when the path is specified. Suppose path = "progfiles/harry/sample.dll". How to find the sample.dll version. Since I am using .net framework 3.5 SP1, I cannot use FileVersionInfo. I tried Assembly.LoadFrom. But the problem I am facing with LoadFrom is "If an assembly with the same identity is already loaded, LoadFrom returns the loaded assembly even if a different path was specified."

Comment: So, *why* can't you use `FileVersionInfo`?

Comment: FileVersionInfo is not supported for .net framework 3.5 SP1

Comment: @BadhriRavikumar According to whom? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @BadhriRavikumar Huh? [I don't think so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo(v=vs.71).aspx)...

Comment: @mr47 - FileVersionInfo is supported for .net framework 3.5. But not for 3.5 SP1. I have tried this.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus - I could not use FileVersionInfo. What could be the problem.? I have added System.Diagnostics

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, you could just load your assembly into *another* AppDomain.

```
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("tmp");
var version = domain.Load().GetName(path).Version;
```

---

**EDIT:**

You are targeting Windows CE, so can use the [GetFileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910661.aspx) function.

[Here](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2010/09/28/GettingNativeFileInfoInTheCompactFramework.aspx) is a full code sample how to use this function from within .Net/C#.

Comment: I could not find Load() function in domain? Should I add something?

Comment: What do mean you *could not find* it. Do you get a compiler error? [It is there...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwzhhcfk)

Comment: Error - 'System.AppDomain' does not contain a definition for 'Load' and no extension method 'Load' accepting a first argument of type 'System.AppDomain' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I am getting this error.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you use and which `Target Framework` is set in your project setting?

Comment: Target Framework is Windows CE and I am using Visual Studio 2008 version 9.0.30729.1 SP and .net framework is version 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 0):

Example code to find version of DLL library:

```
Version ver = Assembly.LoadFrom("Library.dll").GetName().Version;
```

Edit 1:
OK, for getting already executing assembly you can try this example:

```
Assembly SampleAssembly;
SampleAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(ObjectLoadedFromDLL.GetType());
Version ver = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

And links to MSDN this full documentation of this method: [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx)

Comment: The OP had specific issues with this method; the inability to load a DLL that has the same identity as an already loaded one.

Comment: @coirius - I think you didnt understand my question. I said "If an assembly with the same identity is already loaded, LoadFrom returns the loaded assembly even if a different path was specified." I want to know the solution in this case

Comment: @coirius - If suppose, sample.dll is already loaded once and I have another dll file with the same name at the location path = "progfiles/harry/sample.dll". Now I want dll file version located at path. But whenever I try to load sample.dll, by default it is taking the previously loaded one. Check the first disadvantage here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AssemblyName` :

```
var assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assemblyPath);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(assemblyName.Version);
```

Comment: AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName is not available in .netcf